# Java adding static methods to a class

Tags: java, oop

Ok guys,

Here's a question more of principle than of fact.

I have a data-structure that is used on both a client and a server.

However, on the server end, I want functionality to create the client from some sort of datastore (at the moment SQL, it used to be serialized data, but it doesn't matter).

Originally I had a giant class called something like 'Datastore' which had static methods for retrieving any stored object.

While not terrible, that's not exactly OO, and it's not exactly scalable.

So I considered moving these static methods to the datastructures themselves. However, that would mean that the shared client libraries then knew how to retrieve objects from my datastore - which is kind of silly.

So I'm now creating new classes for each object in a new datastore package, each of which holds the static methods for retrieving one object from the datastore.

My question is, how do I signify the relationship between these data manager classes and the objects that they retrieve?

Functionally, it doesn't matter. The static methods work fine. But I want to indicate to future me and other future developers that the data retriever class and the object class are tightly linked.

My first thought was to make the data retriever extend the data structure. However, that would then require declaring default constructors and implying that the class could be instantiated - which it can, but why would you?

My second thought was to then make the data retriever extend the data structure, but be abstract. That would flag the tight relationship to other developers, and also make it clear that only new methods were being added, no new fields.

However, extending a concrete class with an abstract class seems really strange, and Java still make me create default constructors.

Comment: Considering the question again in the light of the responses here, a T.S. Eliot quote is brought to mind: 
    
"We shall not cease from exploration //
And the end of all our exploring //
Will be to arrive where we started //
And know the place for the first time."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, how do I signify the relationship between these data manager classes and the objects that they retrieve?

This is a standard industry problem: how to get data from a database into an application. The common solution is to use the *DAO pattern*, which is to have a Data Access Object (DAO) responsible for retrieving an object from the database.

If you are retrieving an employee's personal information, salary, etc., you could have an EmployeeDAO class which would retrieve it from the appropriate table. If you are retrieving a company's profits, locations, number of employees, you could have a CompanyDAO class to retrieve this object from the database.

On top of this could be a service layer, for performing business logic; also, a DAO manager, for instantiating the DAOs and returning references to whatever classes need them.

Comment: Ok, so basically since the DAO is a common pattern, simply naming the class ObjectDAO will indicate the kind of dependency intended, without need for extending the other class. Is that right?

Comment: Well, you want to have many DAOs, not one central DAO. The point is not to have one DAO that gets all data, but one for each abstraction: e.g., PersonDAO, EmployeeDAO, CompanyDAO, etc. It's okay to extend a DAO too. EmployeeDAO can be a subclass of PersonDAO. The name indicates (A) it's a data access object (B) what type of object it retrieves.

Answer (score 1):

You can still merge concepts of Repository Design Pattern and DAO Pattern, taking the application in a more concise abstraction level. The Repository acts as domain-level abstraction. Example:

```
public class EmployeeBO implements EmployeeRepository { // implementation of a Business Object Domain-model

     @Inject
     private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO; // really implementation of data access


     @Override
     public  boolean createEmployee(String name){ // domain-oriented method
          // ... some validation
          employeeDAO.save(new Employee(name)); // really data access/persistence implementation
     }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps some more explanation of terms used here, and what is achieved?